# Php class Variable as function parameter

Tags: php, function, class, variables, parameters

How is it possible to use  a class variable as a function parameter?

Example:

```
class Test {

    protected $img = '';

    protected function foo($var = $this->img)
    {
       ... some code ...
    }

}
```

Thus is this good practice?

Comment: You don't. Test if `$var` is.. something, if it isn't use `$this->img`,

Comment: `$this` refers to the current object instantiated from the class and therefore sort of doesn't exist until `new Test()` has been called; you can use a class constant for default data though `protected function foo($var = self::IMG) { ... }`

Comment: You cant have a variable as a default argument value

Comment: @JonStirling is that good practice?

Comment: Is it good practise? It totally depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure, but I thing you can't. You can achieve the same like this:

```
class Test {

    protected $img = '';

    protected function foo($var = null)
    {

        if(is_null($var))
            $var = $this->img;

       ... some code ...
    }

}
```